# Trajectories with collisions... And plasma guns

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, backtracking

I'm creating a game with plasma guns:

[image]

It's easy to compute the trajectory of the plasma ray starting from the gun.

However, another ray may come from afar:
[image]

As everybody knows, plasma rays are deviated when they collide. In fact, they are always deviated 90°, away from the other ray:

[image]

Space is discreet (like a chess board). Each tile may contain either a plasma gun, a plasma ray or nothing. Rays can go either straight or diagonally.
An important precision: rays are "instant", they do not take any time to propagate.

**I need to compute a "solution" trajectory for all rays that satisfies all constraints.**

I can easily compute a ray propagation step by step, but if a collision is detected with other ray, it seems that I will need to "backtrack" that ray up to the point of collision, to then restart propagating it correctly.

Any suggestion of an algorithm to do this?

Here is a bit of pseudo code, just to put down some definitions:

```
type Dir = N | NE | E | SE | S | SW | W | NW
type RayElem = {x: Int, y: Int, dir: Dir} 
type Ray = [RayElem]

-- propagate all rays one step
propagateAll :: [Ray] -> [Ray]
propagateAll = ...

-- Advance a ray one step
step :: [RayElem] -> [RayElem]
step = ...

--check if a ray element is colliding with any other ray
checkCollision :: RayElem -> [Ray] -> Boolean
checkCollision = ...
```

I'm using lists to store the rays, but maybe I should use graphs (nodes being collisions)?

I would be also glad if you point me to some class of similar algorithms/research...
Thanks!

PS. Note that collisions can have cascading consequences.
For example in this situation:
[image]

If I fire the red plasma gun, This is what I should get:

[image]

The green trajectory was affected by the new collision between red and blue. More collisions can also appear:

[image]

Last but not least, paradoxes can appear:

[image]

And also, non trivial solutions:

[image]

Comment: What happens if two guns fire directly at each other? A gun fires at a mirror that is reflecting back at the gun? Or the paradox that you describe? I think there often must not be a solution at all.

Comment: "As everybody knows, plasma rays are deviated when they collide. In fact, they are always deviated 90°, away from the other ray" no expert on the matter but plasma is ionized stuff so I would expect curved trajectory either repel or attract the 2 "rays" on proximity based on momentum/density and charge of the particles involved ... unless its EVO but in such case its not ray but a blob and also hard to say if still accounts as plasma as its behaves veeeery differently ...

Comment: @btilly when two guns fire directly at each other, a collision is created at mid-distance. Each ray is deviated 90° to the right. In the case of a paradox, the engine should return no solutions. The case where a gun fires at a mirrors that is reflecting back at the gun should be treated as a paradox IMO, because the subsequent collision that will be created in front of the mirror will prevent the ray to hit the mirror in the first place.

Comment: @Spektre this is just a thought experiment, nothing to do with real physics!

Comment: *rays are "instant", they do not take any time to propagate* *compute a ray propagation step by step, but if a collision is detected with other ray, it seems that I will need to "backtrack" that ray up to the point of collision* are (in my IMHO) contradictory. Collisions introduce a kind of time, collisions are ordered events in time. You also says *two guns fire directly at each other, a collision is created at mid-distance*, was not it because there is some kind of time? I think that your model is not completely/correctely defined. Paradox are, because your model is very strange.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I agree that the model does not feel completely consistent. However, you should distinguish the "computation" phase from the "solution" itself. The solution as a whole should be consistent, in an instant way. If rays took "time" to propagate, the "paradox" setup would not be paradoxical: it would just be an oscillator. The ray would first hit the mirrors, go back to itself, self-collide and interrupt the part of the ray going through mirrors. This would in turn prevent the collision a bit later and the cycle continue.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès if the rays took time=1 to cover one tile, this oscillator would have a period of 7 (the time it takes to go through the mirrors back to collision). However, with "instant" rays, this setup is really paradoxical. However, the way you "compute" the solutions is up to you. Maybe it includes steps, maybe not. Regarding the case where two guns fire directly at each other, I'm not really sure about this rule, actually.

Comment: I must add that solutions might not be unique. Sometimes there are zero solutions (paradox), sometimes 1 (classical case) but also 2 solutions or more. See the non-trivial case: the ray can go straight OR through the mirrors. Both solutions are valid and should be output by the engine.

Comment: *instant ray* is the problem I think. Take a ray with two possible "obstacles" in front, which one do you chose? I bet the "closest" one, so you order things and that implies a concept of time/speed. If you take the second, what this would then mean (think of a third possible one, etc)?

Comment: By obstacles, do you mean potential collisions (like in the case of 3 guns above)? There is no time, but there is still causality involved. In the case of the 3 guns, the first collision (red gun) prevents the second collision (green gun) to happen. The opposite is not true: the second collision cannot prevent the first collision. So yes, events are ordered by causality chains, but no need to define a propagation time for that to happen.

Comment: Not a full answer, but this looks very much like a variant of "motorcycle graphs". Quite possibly some methods from there (in particular priority queue-based methods) could be adapted.

Comment: @Sneftel, thanks for the hint! Motorcycle graphs are very interesting. The difference with the Motorcycle graph is that here the motorcycles are bouncing at collisions, instead of dying. Also, here there is no need for speed: intersecting trajectories will always produce the same collision, no matter who arrives first.

Comment: @cdupont I would simplify this simply by ray will interact only with different ray (different color) that way you would have no paradoxes ... another way is instead of turn your ray on collision split it into original and turned (each with half intensity) that should get rid of paradoxes too...

Comment: @Spektre, this specific setup is interesting because it creates paradoxes. The ultimate objective is to study paradoxes, so I don't want to get rid of them! If a paradox is detected, the engine should output the message "No solutions".